# How to remove duplicates (nodes with the same fields) from drupal 7 view?

Tags: drupal, view

For example: we have some products with diff colors. I want to get its colors.
If I add to view fields the color field I will get duplicates (colors) in output.

Needs realize something like `GROUP BY field_color_value` in sql-query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand at all what do you want to do. For example, what are the colors? (terms, item from a text listbox field...).

Without having this information I can tell you that in some view's style settings (click on the gear icon next to style), you can group by the fields you have in the view's field section.

Comment: Yes. I of course used taxonomy type of view, but than i cant used some necessary fileds in arguments.

Comment: I can't answer to this without more information. Views are very complex and you are omiting important data (it's a taxonomy view, you need to filter by argument...). I still don't know what do you want as output

Comment: thanks. i solved the problem by myself. i remove duplicates from view template. that is't good, but it works.